Applying Lie's Theorem in linear algebra
I want to apply Lie's theorem in linear algebra in the following way:
We have $m$ matrices $A_1,A_2, \cdots, A_m \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$
Let $V=\langle A_1, A_2, \ldots,A_m \rangle$ be the vector space over $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ generated by the $m$ given matrices.
Let $\mathfrak{L}={\langle A_1, A_2, \ldots,A_m \rangle}_{\mathcal{Lie}}$ be the Lie algebra over generated by the $m$ given matrices with the Lie bracket as the commutator (i.e. $[A,B]=AB-BA$).
Now if I know that $\mathfrak{L}$ is a finite dimensional and solvable (i.e. if I denote $\mathfrak{L}_1=[\mathfrak{L},\mathfrak{L}], \mathfrak{L}_2=[\mathfrak{L}_1,\mathfrak{L}_1], \cdots, \mathfrak{L}_k=[\mathfrak{L}_{k-1},\mathfrak{L}_{k-1}]$ eventually $\mathfrak{L}_k=\{O_n\}$), then by Lie's Theorem, we know that the matrices $A_1,A_2, \cdots, A_m$ are simultaneously triangularizable.
Fisrt main question: Am I applying Lie's theorem correctly?
Let's take a simple example.
We have $2$ matrices $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A=AB-BA$
I want to prove that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously triangularizable.
$A=AB-BA$ means that $A=[A,B]$
Let $V=\langle A,B \rangle$ be the vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $A$ and $B$.
$[A,A]=O_n \in V$
$[A,B]=A \in V$
$[B,B]=O_n \in V$
Using the last $3$ statements as well as the bilinearity of the commutator bracket we get that $V$ is also closed under the commutator bracket, therefore it is a finite dimensional Lie algebra.
Now let's prove that $V$ is solvable.
$V=\langle A,B \rangle$
$[A,A]=O_n \in V$
$[A,B]=A \in V$
$[B,B]=O_n \in V$
Due to the facts from above as well as the bilinearity of the commutator bracket, we get that $[V,V]=\langle A \rangle$.
Let's denote $V_1=[V,V]=\langle A \rangle$
Now it is obvious that $[V_1,V_1]=\{O_n\}$ so $\mathfrak{L}$ is also solvable.
Now, by Lie's theorem, we get that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneous triangularizable, so there exists an invertible matrix $U \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $U^{-1}AU$ and $U^{-1}BU$ are both upper triangular matrices.
Second main question: Is this proof correct? Did I apply Lie's theorem correctly?
I am not very experienced in Lie Algebra so please, point out any mistake, even notation mistakes.

Yes, everything is correct and well-written.

Thank you, Alek!

You could mention the assumptions to Lie's theorem. The Lie algebra has to be finite-dimensional, solvable, and over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (you said this implicitly, of course, but only for $\Bbb C$). The notation $O_n$ is not really used, it is simply $[B,B]=0$. Furthermore, the derived series for $L$ has terms $L^{(n)}$, not $L_n$ (because of the notation for homology $H_n(L)$).

Got it! But in the way in which I apply Lie's Theorem, I will always work with a finite-dimensional Lie algebra, right? Because if I work with $n \times n$ matrices the dimension will be at most $n^2$. I would appreciate if someone could confirm this.

I don’t get it. For example, $\mathcal{M}{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ has the structure of a Lie algebra because it is closed under the Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$
So the dimension of the Lie algebra is the same as the dimension of the vector field, in our case $\mathcal{M}{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$ that has dimension $n^2$

I read that if we have a vector field $(V,+,•)$ and a Lie bracket [•,•] such that $\mathfrak{L}=(V,+,•, [])$ is a Lie algebra, then $dim(\mathfrak{L})=dim(V)$
And $dim(V)$ is always at most $n^2$ for any subfield of $\mathcal{M}{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ because  $\mathcal{M}{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ has dimension  equal to $n^2$ in the sense of vector fields.

Yes, this is true. It was not clear to me, that we consider subspaces of $M_n(K)$. You can generate infinite-dimensional Lie algebras by two elements (e.g., matrices). For example, take generators $e_1,e_2$ and take Lie brackets $e_{i+1}=[e_1,e_i]$ for all $i\ge 2$.

Oh, yes. I know that in general, $2$ elements could generate an infinite-dimensional Lie algebra

Your wrote "vector space over $M_n(K)$", and the over confused me. You mean a subspace then. A vector space is over a field.

I am very sorry. I wanted to write "vector space over $\mathbb{C}$", but I made I typo. I wanted to mean subspace, exactly like you said. I have edited the statement. Thanks a lot for all the help, and sorry for the confusion. It was my bad.
